# get запрос через прокси c#

Tags: c#, get, proxy

Как отправить get запрос на определенный урл через прокси? Результат обрабатывать никак не надо, необходимо просто обратится к апи сервиса через прокси.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("[ultimate destination of your request]");
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("[your proxy address]", [your proxy port number]);
myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
request.Proxy = myproxy;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо.